# Selenium WebDriverException Session not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

We set up selenium grid on was and frequently seeing these errors

```
   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Session [b5d972ffde50571472d132b73d8df799] not available and is not among the last 1000 terminated sessions.
    Active sessions are[]
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: 'DESKTOP-37JVVAA', ip: '169.254.225.143', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver
    Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 80.0.3987.106, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.ROw2PX}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:33013}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webdriver.remote.sessionid: b5d972ffde50571472d132b73d8...}
    Session ID: b5d972ffde50571472d132b73d8df799
```

Comment: Are you sure the grid is up and running with the given configuration?

Comment: Yes its happening some time after actions on browser.

Comment: Sound like you need to increase your browserTimeout. webDriver.manage().timeouts()